# Include Bitcode for iOS Content is disabled

Tags: ios, xcode

What's the reason behind the disabling of the **Include Bitcode for iOS Content** in Xcode when submitting a build?

[image]

To add more context, the project is somewhat old, 2015-2017, and I'm using Xcode 11.5.

The project has a WatchKit app extension too.

Comment: it likely detects that your build does not have bitcode therefore you cannot upload with bitcode

Comment: Cool! I can indeed see that the bitcode was enabled. I hadn't thought about that! Would you like to post your comment as an answer though? I believe there's not a question that is similar to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode will detect that the build you have selected to upload does not contain bitcode so that option would not be suitable, so the option to upload with it is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

For my case a legacy project had **Enable Bitcode** set to **No** in Xcode Build Settings. To re-enable this options follow the following steps and try to archive again.

1. Select Xcode Project
2. Select your project Target
3. Select Build Setting
4. **Enable Bitcode -> Yes**

Then archive your project again.

Reference: [Include bitcode for iOS content](https://twih1203.medium.com/xcode-include-bitcode-for-ios-content-%EB%B9%84%ED%99%9C%EC%84%B1%ED%99%94-%EC%83%81%ED%83%9C%EC%9D%BC-%EB%95%8C-disabled-3d06a0bf1d0f)